# Did Krishna stop time while preaching the Gita to Arjuna?

Tags: krishna

Did Krishna stop time? If he did, then sanjaya must have not been able to narrate to dritarashtra and hence we would have never known it. If he did not, how was so much preached — they would have been sacked to death in no time.

Comment: The destroyer there is no satisfactory answer in that question. You have yourself asked for Shastra Pramana. Moreover the answer is completely wrong.

Comment: The war didn't  begin when Krishna was preaching Gita to Arjuna and so there's no question of kauravas butchering the pandavas during the preaching session. And I'm not sure whether he stopped time or not. I often wondered the same thing that how come the kauravas were not getting impatient when Krishna and Arjuna were absorbed in discussion. lol.